# Sentences are not getting splitted using CoreNLP Server

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

Having a review text like:

> "*The tutu's was for my neice... She LOVED IT!!!  It fit well and will fit her for some time with the elastic waist.... great quality and very  inexpensive!  I would buy her another easily.*"

and sending it to the CoreNLP Server:

```py
properties = {
    "tokenize.whitespace": "true",
    "annotators": "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse",
    "outputFormat": "json"
}


if not isinstance(paragraph, str):
    paragraph = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', paragraph).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

result = self.nlp.annotate(paragraph, properties=properties)
```

Is giving me this result:

```
{  
   u'sentences':[  
      {  
         u'parse':u'SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE',
         u'index':0,
         u'tokens':[  
            {  
               u'index':1,
               u'word':u'The',
               u'lemma':u'the',
               u'pos':u'DT',
               u'characterOffsetEnd':3,
               u'characterOffsetBegin':0,
               u'originalText':u'The'
            },
            {  
               u'index':2,
               u'word':u"tutu's",
               u'lemma':u"tutu'",
               u'pos':u'NNS',
               u'characterOffsetEnd':10,
               u'characterOffsetBegin':4,
               u'originalText':u"tutu's"
            },
            // ...
            {  
               u'index':34,
               u'word':u'easily.',
               u'lemma':u'easily.',
               u'pos':u'NN',
               u'characterOffsetEnd':187,
               u'characterOffsetBegin':180,
               u'originalText':u'easily.'
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I noticed that sentences are not getting splitted - any idea what the problem could be?

If I am using the http://localhost:9000 webinteface then I see those sentences being splitted correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why but the problem appeared to come from `tokenize.whitespace`. I just commented it out:

```
properties = {
    #"tokenize.whitespace": "true",
    "annotators": "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse",
    "outputFormat": "json"
}
```